# Need help writing an inner join query

Tags: mysql, join

```
$query= mysqli_query($db,"SELECT a.*, b.collection_id , c.contract_id,
d.customer_name FROM rentals_invoice  
AS b INNER JOIN rental_collection as a ON (b.collection_id = a.collection_id) 
AS c INNER JOIN rental_contract as b ON (c.contract_id = b.contract_id) 
AS d INNER JOIN customer_info as c ON (d.customer_id = c.customer_id)");
```

I have tables a, b, c, d

'a' have fkey of 'b'

'b' have fkey of 'c'

'c' have fkey of 'd'

I want to get data from all of them, and I don't know how to get it through inner join or any other type of join in a single query.

I am a beginner.

Comment: What is wrong with the above query? Don't you get the expected answer?

Comment: It looks like you've already written the query. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: You probably have some missing data in one of the tables, I would use a left join instead of inner

Comment: where is 'd' defined ? Should rentals_invoice not be 'a' and so on  ?

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced your aliases. You are overwriting your aliases. You also can use the `using` to simplify this.

```
FROM rentals_invoice  AS b 
INNER JOIN rental_collection as a using(collection_id) 
INNER JOIN rental_contract AS c using(contract_id) 
INNER JOIN customer_info as d using(customer_id)");
```

I also would use aliases that relate to the actual table name. `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. aren't useful and will be hard to diagnose later.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($db,"
    SELECT a.*,b.collection_id,c.contract_id,d.customer_name 
    FROM `rentals_invoice` As a
    INNER JOIN rental_collection As b ON b.collection_id = a.collection_id
    INNER JOIN rental_contract AS c ON c.contract_id = b.contract_id
    INNER JOIN customer_information AS d ON d.customer_cnic = c.customer_cnic
");
```

Thanks to all who helped or tried to help me, i got the understanding of JOIN.